# HP Proliant ML150 G3 PSU change to Corsair VS650 PSU

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

I'm new for having experience about power supply, i just bought second HP Proliant ML150 G3, and looks like the original PSU was broken, and i'm already have Corsair VS650 PSU which is same Power 650W, but when i'm trying replacing the original PSU, my Corsair PSU doesn't have 10 Pin.

Only PCI-E Connector, so how do i suppose to do?, is it my new PSU Corsair Uncompatible, and could i do damage when i'm installing this new PSU, because i just worried about the voltage.

[image]

Comment: You could create an adapter for this purpose. could you take a picture, that shows the colors of the wires?